# Angular populate reactive form with get request in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having trouble creating an update component that reads the passed in id from the url, makes a get request, and populates a reactive form. I can confirm that the get request is returning what it should in the network tab of the browser.

**In my service:**

```
productUrl= 'http://localhost:8080/api/products';

  getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    const url = `${this.productUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Product>(url);
  }
```

**In my component:**

```
  product: Product;

  productForm= this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProduct();
    console.log(this.product);

    this.productForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.product.name);
    this.productForm.controls['price'].setValue(this.product.price);
  }

  getProduct(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.productService.getProduct(id)
      .subscribe(product=> this.product = product);
  }
```

Comment: I did this one for something else but maybe it will help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf2mhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage.component.ts also check routing setup

Comment: `this.getProduct()` is asynchronous. You can convert that observable to promise via `.toPromise()` and use async/await. Or add them into the subscribe.

Comment: @penleychan, NO. Blake must make the setValues INSIDE subscribe function. FutherMore Blake, you can do `this.productForm.setValue(this.product)`

Comment: @Eliseo, Why is that the only option he has to go with doing that? It is valid to do async await.

Comment: @penleychan I'm sorry, I feel that the way to express my comment was not the most appropriate. I want to say that, in my opinion, it is more natural to use the Observables and subscribe to them. Convert an Observable in Promise is a work around I do not think necessary (Angular work mostly using Observables, not Promise), but it's just an opinion. My apologies if you bothered my comment.

Comment: @Eliseo, no problem, converting to promise is not a workaround, it is in fact a common way if you are doing a single event, which in this case he is. It is essentially the same thing when you do `subscribe` in this case. I stand by my comment, both option is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting the data to form before it comes from the backend, (subscribe is asynchronous, which means the setvalue functions will execute while the subscribe function is in the process )the best way to do is to trigger the setValue/patch function when the data has arrived from the backend like this

```
getProduct(): void {
const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.productService.getProduct(id)
      .subscribe(product=> {
       this.product = product;
       console.log(this.product);
       this.productForm.patchValue({
price: this.product.price
name: this.product.name
});     
     }
   );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting the from before the data is come form server so you  should set the form after data come  form server  as follows:

```
    product: Product;

      productForm= this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        price: ['', Validators.required]
      });

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getProduct();

      }

      getProduct(): void {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.productService.getProduct(id)
          .subscribe(product=> {
           this.product = product;
           console.log(this.product);

           this.productForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.product.name);
           this.productForm.controls['price'].setValue(this.product.price);
         }
       );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `pathValue` wth the value

```
    this.productService.getProduct(id)
      .subscribe(product=> { 
                 this.product = product;
                 if (this.productForm) {
                     this.productForm.patchValue(this.product); 
                     //  this.productForm.patchValue(this.product, {emitEvent: false}); if you don't want valueChange on form be fired 

                 }
                });
```